# Using DLL that using COM in C#

Tags: c#, com, dll

I have been writing DLL on C++, that will be use in C#.
DLL have some function, where I call

```
hres =  CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
```

and next call

```
hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL, 
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );
```

There are **no error** then I trying to use this dll in **C++**. But if I call function from DLL via C# application I see Error **(80010106)    Cannot change thread mode after it is set.** I changed

```
hres =  CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
```

to

```
hres = CoInitialize(NULL);
```

After this changes error appear after **CoInitializeSecurity**:

```
(80010119)    Security must be initialized before any
                          interfaces are marshalled or unmarshalled. It
                          cannot be changed once initialized.
```

How resolve this trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove the call to `CoInitializeEx` and `CoInitializeSecurity` from your DLL. They have already been called on the thread - that's why you get these errors.

However, if your DLL is trying to initialize a COM thread as a multithreaded apartment, and your C# application is calling the DLL on a single-threaded apartment, then you may have a basic incompatibility. It depends whether the line of code that specified `COINIT_MULTITHREADED` was a deliberate choice with a reason behind it, or just something that seemed to work at the time it was originally written.

Comment: Thanks. Please have a look at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29385515/938668). I am unable to figure out where to place these calls in a managed app.