# Using CoInitializeEx on WinForms threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, com, apartments

I am working an SDK for a DSLR camera which has the following instructions:

> Notes on Developing Windows Applications When creating applications
>   that run under Windows, a COM initialization is required for each
>   thread in order to access a camera from a thread other than the main
>   thread. To create a user thread and access the camera from that
>   thread, be sure to execute CoInitializeEx( NULL,
>   COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED ) at the start of the thread and
>   CoUnInitialize() at the end. Sample code is shown below. This is the
>   same when controlling EdsVolumeRef or EdsDirectoryItemRef objects from
>   another thread, not just with EdsCameraRef.

```
void TakePicture(EdsCameraRef camera)
{
    // Executed by another thread
    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthread(threadProc, 0, camera);
    // Block until finished
    ::WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );
}

void threadProc(void* lParam)
{
    EdsCameraRef camera = (EdsCameraRef)lParam;
    CoInitializeEx( NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED );
    EdsSendCommand(camera, kEdsCameraCommand_TakePicture, 0);
    CoUninitialize();
    _endthread();
}
```

My application is a C# WinForms app and normally, I use the managed thread class and Control.Invoke functions to avoid cross-thread issues.

Since I do not have sample source code in C# for consuming the SDK, my question is, is it useful and/or necessary to use `CoInitializeEx` in an app marked with the `[STAThread]` attribute?

I have not come across a scenario were I would need to have my app create a new apartment for threads so some insight would be helpful to understand threading models better.

**UPDATE:** After reading some more about apartments and COM, it is beginning to make some sense. Now I'm wondering what the .NET managed thread class defaults to and can we specify an apartment model in a managed way to each thread without P/Invoke?

Comment: Yes, as Hans says in his answer below, you call Thread.SetApartmentState *before* starting the thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> a COM initialization is required for each thread

Yes, rock-hard requirement.  So much so that the CLR does this automatically without you having to help.  Every .NET thread has CoInitializeEx() called before it starts running.

The CLR needs to know what argument to pass to CoInitializeEx(), selecting between STA and MTA.  For the startup thread of your Winforms program it is determined by the [STAThread] attribute on your Main() method in Program.cs.  It *must* be STA, a hard requirement for threads that display UI.  For any thread that you start yourself it is determined by your call to Thread.SetApartmentState(), default is MTA.  For any thread-pool thread, like the one used by BackgroundWorker or Task or QUWI, it is always MTA and cannot be changed.  An automatic consequence of such a thread never being able properly support STA if it is used correctly.

Which is also what your code snippet is doing wrong, it is illegal to start an STA thread and not pump a message loop.  You tend to get away with it by accident.  Sometimes you do not and code will deadlock or fail in other ways, like not raising expected events.  Since the vendor sanctioned it doing wrong, it probably does not matter here.  But if you ever notice deadlock then you'd know where to look.

Long story short, you must not call CoInitializeEx() yourself, it was already done.

Comment: If I create a managed `Thread` and call, `ThreadInstance.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)`, will that take care of pumping the message loop? Or do you mean that there is not much I can do expect wait for a deadlock and ask the vendor for support?

Comment: No, you have to take care of it yourself.  Application.Run().  Which is what STA is all about, you just make a *promise* that you'll do it right and COM takes your word for it.  The vendor's code snippet says that it will work by accident if you don't call it, there isn't much reason to assume that it won't.  Well, as long as you don't stray too much from the sample code perhaps . An example of code for a functional STA thread [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034).

Comment: If the only thing the thread does is call the 3rd party API `EdsSendCommand`, and that appears to be a normal blocking call, then there won't be an opportunity to pump messages during that call, and it could be okay assuming that API returns quickly. OTOH I have seen bizarre problems such as the Windows shell hanging up when the user attempts to open a Word document, apparently due to a non-pumping COM thread in a different process. For a really short-lived thread it could be okay. (But then why make it a separate thread?)

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: Most of the calls will indeed be very short-lived using `EdsSendCommand` while a few will be long-running threads displaying a live view of the camera. Thanks for the heads up about your experience with crashes. Will revert back to this question if I run into any.